# Listener doesn't work when changing Panel

Tags: java, multithreading, actionlistener

i've got  a problem with my program. I'm finishing to develop Pacman for my exam but I've a trouble when I change Panel from "menu" to "game" Panel.
Precisely in the main frame I've added two Panel : the "menu" panel and the "game " one. If I don't add the menu panel , the game (and above all, the listener) works; but if I also add the menu panel, when I press the "start game" button in it , the "setVisible" property of menu will sets up to false and the new thread will starts. In this case the problem is that the listener doesn't work .

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    boolean gameOver = false;

    MainFrame mf = new MainFrame(FRAME_WIDTH, FRAME_HEIGHT, TITLE);

    // board is a logic map; gb is the graphic map of the game
    Board board = new Board();
    GraphicBoard gb = new GraphicBoard(mf, board);
    gb.setLocation(150, 0);


    Background background = new Background(mf.getWidth(), mf.getHeight(), BACKGROUND_COLOR);
    background.add(gb);


    PacmanThread thread = new PacmanThread(gb, gameOver);

    Menu menu = new Menu(mf.getWidth(), mf.getHeight(), thread);

    mf.add(menu);
    mf.add(background);

    mf.setResizable(false);
    mf.setVisible(true);
}
```

In menu.java is present a subclass, so

```
public class Menu extends JPanel{
public Menu(int pWidth, int pHeight, PacmanThread pThread) {
    this.setLayout(null);
    this.setSize(pWidth, pHeight);

    this.thread = pThread;

    initComponent();
}


    private class StartGame implements ActionListener {

        private Menu menu;

       public StartGame(Menu pMenu) {
           this.menu = pMenu;
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) { //<--- is the problem here? what I should add?
           menu.setVisible(false);
           thread.start();         
        }

    }

}
```

Finally tha actionListener is present in a class called Pacman.java

Comment: Listeners only respond when the component its added to is in focus. If you added it to the button (idk if you did, you never show us where you added it), the button must be in focus for the listener to work

Comment: Wait... what means i never show you where I added it? However I tried to set up "frame.requestFocus()" and now it works :). Thank you!

Comment: What I meant was I couldn't find the `addActionListener` method in your code. But I'm glad it worked :)